# Rodar Processo Em Janela com PHP

Tags: php, linux

Estou utilizando o S.O Linux ubuntu e rodando meu website em um servidor Apache. Através do PHP estou tentando fazer rodar um executável que está em um diretório especifico, mas quero que esse processo rode em background e em alguma janela para ele ser mantido.

Tentei diversos comando `exec` `system` e `shell_exec` e no momento está assim, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
$startOT = "";
if ( isset($_GET['Server']) ) {
    $startOT = trim($_GET['Server']);
}

if ($startOT == "Start") { 
    if (substr_count(shell_exec('sudo pstree'),'tfs') >= 1) { 
        echo 'Server is executing';
    }
    else {
        $startCommand = 'cd /var/www/html/datapacks/baiak860/ && sudo screen && sudo ./tfs';
        $out = shell_exec($startCommand);
        echo $out;
        echo "Server has been started!";
    }
}
```

Comment: não entendi bem você quer rodar em background ou quer que exiba uma janela?

Comment: Quero apenas que inicie o processo e o deixe rodando em uma janela. A janela que me refiro seria utilizar o comando "screen -S ./executavel".

Comment: Qual dos comandos? o `config.lua` ou o `sudo pstree`? Você precisa pegar o output desse comando no PHP quando o comando terminar? Ou apenas precisa que o php chame o processo?

Comment: Preciso apenas que ele chame o processo. Unico dado de saida que eu quero é saber se o processo realmente está rodando.

Comment: Entendi `sudo pstree` detecta se já esta rodando, vou tentar formular uma resposta.

Comment: Ta certo obrigado, editei um pouco o post, algumas coisas do comando estavam erradas.

Comment: Só me diz uma coisa, eu não sei bem o que seu script lua faz, mas pelo que entendi vocÊ quer rodar em uma janela de terminal, é isso?

Comment: Veja o post novamente, o comando a ser executado é aquele lá. No meu caso quero iniciar o executável de nome "tfs".

Comment: Tá então só quer o comando tfs em uma janela? Olha esta dificil de entender, tem uma sequencia de comandos, vou postar a resposta veja se ajuda.

Comment: Tá certo, poste para eu dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei bem o que você quer rodar mas vou informar algumas sugestões, nos terminais gnu/linux você pode usar `> /dev/null &` (ou `> /dev/null 2>&1 &`) pra poder executar um comando em *background*, isto faz o PHP não esperar o comando:

```
exec($startedCommand . ' > /dev/null &');
```

ou

```
exec($startedCommand . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Se quer abrir uma nova tela de terminal pode tentar isto:

```
exec('xterm -e "' . $startedCommand . '"');
```

Se isto segurar o processo do php tente combinado com os comandos anteriores:

```
exec('xterm -e "' . $startedCommand . '" > /dev/null &');
```

Se tiver suporte as ferramentas do Gnome (Unity e xfce acredito que tenham) pode tentar assim:

```
exec('gnome-terminal -e "' . $startedCommand . '"');
```

Se isto segurar o processo do php tente combinado com os comandos anteriores:

```
exec('gnome-terminal -e "' . $startedCommand . '" > /dev/null &');
```

Talvez possa ocorrer algum problema ao passar o parâmetro `-e`, então você pode tentar usar `escapeshellarg`, assim:

```
$startedCommand = escapeshellarg($startedCommand);
exec('xterm -e "' . $startedCommand . '" > /dev/null &');
```

Ou

```
$startedCommand = escapeshellarg($startedCommand);
exec('gnome-terminal -e "' . $startedCommand . '" > /dev/null &');
```

Comment: Ajudou muito, irei tentar agora. Obrigado!

Comment: @AleChaito editei a resposta pois havia um detalhe do qual não citei sobre o `escapeshellarg`. Uma dica quando for perguntar se puder especificar os "locais" aonde quer aplicar algo e como o seu script esta funcionando, por exemplo, "linha tal faz tal coisa", isso ajuda muito a entender o seu problema. Uma boa noite