# Cancelar loop/script em andamento no servidor

Tags: php, ciclo-infinito

Bom dia,
como cancelar um Loop infinito no Script que já está rodando no servidor?

Foi uma rotina que criei para disparo de e-mails, porém por descuido ele está em loop infinito e o processo não para.

Ele já está em andamento no servidor, e eu queria que ele para-se de executar, como faço para interromper o script?

Comment: Que `script` é esse? Quem executa, um `CRON`? Poste mais informações, mais detalhes...já tentou dar um `restart` no `apache`?

Comment: vou tentar dar restart no servidor e verificar se para e dou um retorno

Comment: @KennyRafael Resolvido dando restart, valeu a resposta!

Comment: Precisa de mais detalhes! Está rodando em Windows ou Linux? Cadê o código? Como sabe que ele está rodando?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters para que falar desse jeito ? Parece que está gritando... O cara até já resolveu.

Comment: @Gumball eu é que pergunto pra que tanto mimimi? Eu não estou gritando. Foi apenas um sinal de exclamação.  A pergunta não está clara mesmo, e a pessoa que respondeu praticamente "chutou". É impossível dar uma resposta completa para uma pergunta incompleta.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Eu sabia que está rodando pois estava a enviar emails a todo segundo sem parar. Você escreveu em tom certo, realmente era uma ocasião de desespero. kkkkk.. grato ao interesse, teria me ajudado.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow em português. Minha exclamação não teve "intenções malignas". É que o site precisa ter detalhes o suficiente na pergunta para podermos te ajudar (e também ajudar outras pessoas, pois se estiver bem descrito, outras pessoa acharão seu problema e terá a solução ao olhar sua pergunta).

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus veja que o PHP já pode ter parado, mas o servidor estar com os emails na fila de saída. Não necessariamente vá parar de enviar assim que terminar o script. Mas se a situação estiver muito crítica e vc estiver perto do servidor fisicamente, sempre tem um plano b  :P  http://i.stack.imgur.com/etDFj.jpg

Comment: @Bacco Ótima sua explanação, mas como havia dado um descanso de 1s(sleep) isso não ocorreu.. felizmente. Se não teria problemas maiores.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus talvez convenha limitar seu script por lotes fixos, e chamar no CRON (ou agendador de tarefas se for no Windows). Tem uma série de perguntas no site sobre isso, se precisar.

Comment: Está falando de long polling? Ou de um processo que nada tem haver como PHP, mas você gostaria de controlar via php? Veja se isto faz sentido http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127477/3635 . Obs: Não negativei, mas se você detalhar a resposta posso votar para reabrir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se este programa entrou em loop infinito de forma indesejada, você pode matar o processo responsável através do comando `kill PID`, onde PID é o id do processo referido. Para descobrir o PID, basta listar os processos atuais (acredito que seja com o comando `ps`).

Comment: Agradeço a sua resposta Anderson, ficará no favoritos. Mas parece que resolvi de outra forma, dando restart no servidor, o loop erá de envio de emails, ai ja viu ne.. não podia perder um pouco mais de tempo.